# Classic ASP - Returning a value from a function

Tags: asp-classic

I have a function in Classic ASP which receives a value and in the function it runs through various CASE statements. What I want to do is return the value of that function into a variable that I can use.

For example

```
Function whichNumber(intNumber)
    SELECT CASE intNumber
        CASE 1
            whichNumber = "Yes"
        CASE 2
            whichNumber = "No"
    END SELECT 
END Function
```

When I call that function in the webpage via:

```
whichNumber(intNumberToFunction)
```

I am expecting then the variable "whichNumber" to be either "Yes" or "No". So the next line in the code I use:

```
strNumberText = whichNumber
```

However that results in the error:

**Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'whichNumber'**

If I go back and in the function put the following at the end of the function:

```
Response.Write whichNumber
```

It correctly writes either "Yes" or "No" to the screen. Is there anyway to return the value of the function to a variable to use outside of the function?

Hopefully this makes sense! Reading around the web it seems it might not be possible to return a value from a function like this?

Comment: jazza is correct, I'd just like to add that you should include a default case inside of your select statement because, say you're piping some database output through that function by chance, and intNumber is something other than 1 or 2. Then you're function is going to do one of three things in my experience 1. Explode. 2. Return an empty string. 3. Return a null value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you not need to write

```
strNumberText=whichNumber(intNumberToFunction)
```

The error message is telling you that you have called the function without passing the parameter

Comment: That makes sense. On that basis how would I got about getting the value from that function. Lets say I changed it to:

CASE 1
whichNumberOUT = "Yes"

If I then say strNumberText = whichNumberOUT the value is empty when I use it outside of the function.

Comment: From within the function you don't worry about the parameter in your code. To assign the return value within the function use whichNumber="Yes". When you call the function though, you need the parameter strNumberText=whichNumber(intNumberToFunction). From that point on  strNumberToText contains the returned value

Comment: Ohhhh I see! That all makes sense now :). Thanks for clearing that up :)

Comment: @jazza1000 how would that work if I'm calling that function from a HTML file, given that the HTML and .ASP are separate files? Would I have to referente the .asp file on the call? Would something like 
<p><%=whichNumber(intNumberToFunction%></p> or more would be needed?