# Why does this function not work?

Tags: mysql, function, date, asp-classic

Any idea why this doesn't work?

```
function func_data(datdb)
    dat=(Year(datdb) &"-"& Month(datdb) &"-"& Day(datdb))
    hor=(hour(datdb) &":"& Minute(datdb) &":"& second(datdb))
    varr = dat&" "&hor
end function

data_pt = date
data_mysql = func_data(CDate((now)))
dia_semana = WeekDayName(WeekDay(Now())) 
mes = MonthName(Month(Now()))
hora = time
dataehora = now

response.write "<br>data_pt:"&data_pt
response.write "<br>data_mysql:"&data_mysql
response.write "<br>dia_semana:"&dia_semana
response.write "<br>mes:"&mes
response.write "<br>hora:"&hora
response.write "<br>dataehora:"&dataehora
```

It returns:

```
data_pt:30/04/2015

data_mysql:

dia_semana:quinta-feira

mes:abril

hora:16:03:30

dataehora:30/04/2015 16:03:30
```

As you can see the function time that formats date to insert into mysql dont work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Classic ASP - Returning a value from a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937988/classic-asp-returning-a-value-from-a-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with ASP, but [Classic ASP - Returning a value from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937988/classic-asp-returning-a-value-from-a-function) suggest that you need to change

```
varr = dat&" "&hor
```

to

```
func_data = dat&" "&hor
```

to not only calculate a return value in func_data but to also return it to the caller.